# Processing Excel formulas on the server in PHP

Tags: php, performance, concurrency, phpexcel

I have a rather complex spreadsheet formula. Right now I am using PHPExcel to load the spreadsheet into memory, and I set the cell values of the formula input to the values from a front-end form (using ajax), get the calculated result and send it back to the client.

Is this the best way to this? Or should the formulas be converted to pure php?

If this is an okay method, I have concerns regarding concurrency and memory usage.

The spreadsheet isn't that large, less than 1000 cells. How can I calculate the threshold for concurrency (people clicking calculate on the front end) and memory usage on the server?

What steps can I take to optimise this algorithm (caching for example) whilst balancing performance?

Comment: i would never replace a web app\site with a spreadsheet, but its hard to answerer with out knowing  what the data is

Comment: Well say for instance I wanted to convert the formula to php, is there a good resource for php equivalents of excel functions? Im thinking of  functions like PV, NPV and PMT etc.

Comment: If you do need to write your own code for PV(), NPV(), PMT() and similar Excel functions, then you can use the PHPExcel implementation as the basis for this... it's probably the best resource for PHP equivalents of those functions that you'll find

Comment: Yep thanks again Mark for pointing that out! You summed it up very well in your answer and I believe this is the way to go. Implementing the calc engine will save me good deal of hassle and should prove extremely useful in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have problems doing this as an ajax request for large numbers of concurrent users, because these http requests have no persistence, so you need to load the spreadsheet file for every request. What it does guarantee is that each request runs independently with its own copy of the spreadsheet, so no individual user's request will affect any of the other users requests.

The other extreme is to take all the Excel logic and rewrite it in PHP. You don't give any indication of the complexity of your spreadsheet formulae, so it's difficult to judge how complex a task this would be.

A third option would be to use only PHPExcel's calculation engine, feeding it with the form values and formulae directly. This eliminates the time and memory overheads of loading the spreadsheet file with every request, so could be the easiest and most efficient option. You can find an example of this in the Quadratic2.php example file in the /Tests directory of the PHP distribution.

Comment: Hi Mark. The Calc engine may indeed be the way to go here so that I dont have to re-implement all the functions myself. I didn't realise the calc engine was pluggable right out of the box. That is extremely handy! Will attempt this now. Thanks again!

Comment: I deliberately wrote the calculation engine to work standalone as well as with PHPExcel, though there's a few Excel functions (mainly those in the Information, Lookup and Reference and Database categories) that are dependent on the structure of the spreadsheet itself. As long as you avoid those, then you should be able to use the calculation engine independently of having an instantiated PHPExcel object

Comment: Note also that there will be a completely new implementation of the calculation engine during the course of this year, but it will still be capable of running standalone